# Jenkins setup from code

Tags: jenkins

> Is there a way to setup a Jenkins from code (eg. AWS userscript) doing
>   configurations like setting up a user, configuring GIT and slack
>   plugins?

So far I can install the Jenkins and even add plugins but I'm not able to configure it. This is only possible doing manually afterwards.

I heard about the Jenkins-CLI but don't know how to obtain it, if I just setup the system? Is it also enough to configure the system as I would access it via the UI?

Comment: Hi Iony, did You find any solution? I'm also looking for such solution

Comment: Sadly still not. I found that there is a Jenkins CLI tool you can "download" as a jar from your running instance and then interact with your Jenkins ... but I didnt test how far this is helping.

Comment: @lony Did you find how to achieve this ?

Comment: I just found https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI but didnt proceed and we had to add a manual step. In this step Jenkins is configured rudimentary adding credentials and starting a Job DSL seed job ... in summary no. Any insides would be most welcome!